# Plotly in Editor

Tags: plotly

I have tried to import all these libraries after installing them on cmd

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

I am running this on editor and not in notebook!

but following error is been shown

> Aw, snap! We didn't get a username with your request. Don't have an
>   account? https://plot.ly/api_signup

Answer (score 0):

Code below should work in an editor to open a scatter plot in browser. The required libraries are also listed. (Atom 1.28, Python 3).

**Import libraries**

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
#%matplotlib inline

import json
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
```

**Create a sample dataframe**

```
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
```

**Create traces, layout for plotting**

```
# Create traces
trace = [go.Scatter(
    x = df.x,
    y = df.y,
    mode = 'markers'
)]

layout = go.Layout(
    title = 'Title',
    xaxis = {'title': 'X AXIS'},
    yaxis = {'title': 'Y AXIS'}
)
fig = go.Figure(data=trace,layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig, filename='sample_plot.html')
```

[image]